# TextView align center - Android

Tags: java, android, layout

I have a text view like this,

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

It is aligned in the center horizontally, but now I want to move it 20p to the left from the center. So I tried `android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"`

But it stayed in the middle how can I move it to the left, but have the reference to center?

Here is full xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.spencer.one.SplashScreenActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show your full xml code.

Comment: Please have a look of my answer.

Comment: use padding instead of margin....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>
```

The content is center inside the textView and is 30dp marginLeft

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try `android:paddingRight="30dp"`, something like this.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: okay that moved it, but now wrap content doesn't work, the view extends farther than the characters? Is there another way?

Comment: This doesn't move the textview, its just in the top right corner, it didn't move, I want the reference to be the center of the whole view, so that on any screen the textview will be 30dp left of the center of that screen

Comment: have you copied my whole XML? please see the edits in Parent layout as well.

Comment: OH, my bad, why does the gravity of the relative layout need to be set?

Comment: Gravity of the relative layout is required, if we wants the child of Parent in center, then gravity center should be set.
You can apply which is working in all device.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this code

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:gravity="left"
    />
```

Comment: I want the reference to be the center of the whole view, so that on any screen the textview will be 30dp left of the center of that screen

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:text="Large Text"
android:id="@+id/textView"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>
```

You're trying to move it to the left so making a margin of 20dp in the right would push it 20dp to the left and still maintain center as reference.

Comment: This doesn't move the textview at all, I want the reference to be the center of the whole view, so that on any screen the textview will be 30dp left of the center of that screen

Comment: Oh, I tried doing it without the whole layout information and it worked but now it's different. Try padding instead, change the last two lines of the solution I posted to:        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:paddingRight="30dp"

Answer (score 0):

little tricky but works.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="whatever"
        />
    <View
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

First create linearlayout and put textview inside. And add empty view to give padding.

that's all.

Comment: Also you have to add orientation tag at lineralayout.

Answer (score 0):

you should use padding instead of margin for ...

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:paddingRight="30dp"
/>
```